# How to fine the formula for the volume using cylindrical shells?

Tags: calculus, integration, volume, solid-of-revolution

Use cylindrical shells to find the volume of the solid. The region bounded $y = x^2$ and $y = 1$ is revolved around the line $y = 3$.

The answer is:
$$\int_0^1 4\pi(3-y)y^{1/2}dy$$

Why is it $4\pi$? I understand the formula to be $\int 2πy(f(y))dy$.

Answer (score 0):

The $4\pi$ that you mentioned comes from $2\pi\times 2$. The first $2\pi$ is from $2\pi(3-y)$ which is the circumference of the disk with radius $3-y$. The second $2$ comes from the height of the cylinder which is $2x = 2\sqrt{y}$. And if you put these together you should arrive at the same integral given by the answer that you had above.

Comment: where are you getting those 2's though for that?

Comment: I already explained in my writing. Can you read it a bit more carefully and slowly?

Comment: Then you just did a bad job of explaining it because it still doesn't make sense. You say the second 2 comes from the height which is 2=2√y  where are you getting those 2's from in that equation and how are you deriving that equation?